# Removing MyFaces Orchestra's "conversationContext" GET parameter from static resources (css, images)

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces, orchestra

MyFaces Orchestra adds a `?conversationContext=x` to each resource on a page. Since I'm not using the conversation scope for the public part of my project (only for the admin part), I'd like to get rid of that parameter for two reasons:

- it breaks the browser caching of static resources
- it's ugly :)

I'm now going to take a look at Orchestra's source-code, and perhaps bypass something, but it would be best if there is an option for this I'm unaware of

Comment: I could solve this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368544/1596420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that question is simple, and at the same time a bit of a workaround.
MyFaces orchestra uses a wrapper around the original `HttpServletResponse` in order to encode the `contesationContext` parameter.

There are two options of using Orchestra - with an interceptor (JSF) and a `Filter`.
Both of them try to wrap the response, *if it isn't already wrapped*. So if both the orchestra `Filter` and the interceptor are used, the `Filter` comes firest, wraps the response object, and sets an attribute in the request, which indicates to the interceptor, that it shouldn't wrap the response again.

The `Filter` can be configured to match a certain URL pattern if `conversationContext` is to be added. However, for my needs, that pattern matcher was too simple, so I made my own filter instead. So in order to tell the interceptor NOT to wrap the response, all that has to be done is this:

```
httpRequest.setAttribute(
                RequestParameterServletFilter.REQUEST_PARAM_FILTER_CALLED,
                Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution. I've declared my own filter in web.xml and it gets called correctly. However it seems that when the filter gets called, the `conversationContext` was already applied to the request by some other class. I don't know which class. How have you solved this?

Comment: I have, 3 years ago. Things have probably changed.